# Remove null items from json array properties before model validation in ASP.NET Core 3 Web API

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, model-binding

I am trying to remove null items of json array properties from the users posted payload. My model properties are well annotated wherever validation is required like Required Attribute an so on.

My API method accepts the json into model bindings like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]List<MyModelEntity> myModelEntity) 
{ ... }
```

And some APIs, without List like:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyModelEntity myModelEntity) 
{ ... }
```

GET operations doesn't requires removal of null items. I am using below custom `JsonConverter` to remove null items during deserialization (just trying to do it before model validation): -

```
public class NullListFilterConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.IsGenericType &&
            (objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) || objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
        {
            Type itemType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            return itemType.IsClass;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //with Reflection ==> Performance degradation concern
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var list = existingValue as IList
            ?? (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(objectType.GetGenericArguments()));

        serializer.Populate(reader, list);

        // Filter out null items in the list
        var nonNullItems = list.Cast<object>().Where(x => x != null).ToList();
        list.Clear();
        foreach (var item in nonNullItems)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        // assign null to list count 0
        return list.Cast<object>().Count() == 0 ? null : list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly fine by doing -

1. Removes all null items from the Json array properties if any
2. Model entity are null as usual if extra unmatched properties are supplied in Json payload.

Only issue with this implementation is the some performance concern as it is using Reflection.

To avoid the Reflection, I tried the below: -

```
//without Reflection
public object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jToken = JToken.Load(reader);
    var nullTokens = jToken.SelectTokens("$..[?(@ == null)]");
    nullTokens?.ToList().ForEach(token =>
    {
        if (token.Parent is JArray parentArray)
        {
            parentArray.Remove(token);
        }
        else if (token.Parent is JProperty parentProperty)
        {
            parentProperty.Value = JValue.CreateNull();
        }
    });

    return jToken.ToObject(objectType);
}
```

But somehow this code fails to handle the extra properties supplied in json payload and doesn't make the whole model entity null. It lose the default behavior of handling unmatched model acceptance of web api.

What would be the way to handle this? Any other way to remove null items from json array properties?

Comment: Hi @Anil Kumar, you want to know which methods is better, right? As you said, when using reflection, it will have some performance concern, so you could use the 1st ReadJson method without using the reflection.

Comment: @ZhiLv The 1st method doesn't handle the extra fields if any supplied in json payload. If extra properties are supplied then whole model should become null as usual but it doesn't if I uses 1st approach.

Comment: I think that the use of reflection is the least problem. You are performing things that may be worse and maybe unnecessary, like `Cast<>` multiple times, `Count()` instead of `Any`, `ToList`, `Clear` and so on.

Comment: Will you only be using `List<T>` lists or might you be using `IList<T>` collections that do not inherit from `List<T>`?

Comment: *I am using below custom JsonConverter to remove null items during **serialization*** -- you wrote *serialization* but your code is actually removing null items during **deserialization**.  It's filtering during deserialization that you actually need, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are only interested filtering null values from `List<T>` lists (or properties declared as `IList<T>` which Json.NET will deserialize as `List<T>`) during deserialization, you may take advantage of the fact that [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) also implements the non-generic [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) interface to avoid expensive reflection calls:

```
public class NullListFilterConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => CanConvert(objectType, out var _);

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!CanConvert(objectType, out var itemType))
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Invalid type for {0}: {1}", GetType(), objectType));
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        // Here we take advantage of the fact that List<T> also implements the non-generic IList:
        var list = existingValue as IList ?? (IList)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator!();

        while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            if (serializer.Deserialize(reader, itemType) is var value && value != null)
                list.Add(value);
        }
        // assign null to list count 0
        return list.Count == 0 ? null : list;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");

    static bool CanConvert(Type type, out Type? itemType)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType  && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() is var genType
            // Here we assume that types declared as IList<T> are deserialized as List<T> by Json.NET
            && (genType == typeof(List<>) || genType == typeof(IList<>))) 
        {
            itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            return itemType.IsClass; // TODO: decide whether to filter nullable value types.
        }
        itemType = null;
        return false;
    }   
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader AssertTokenType(this JsonReader reader, JsonToken tokenType) => 
        reader.TokenType == tokenType ? reader : throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0}, expected {1}", reader.TokenType, tokenType));
    
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- [`JsonContract.DefaultCreator()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm) will be a cached delegate invoking the `List<T>` constructor created using code generation techniques by Json.NET during contract creation.  Since the creator delegate will already have been generated and saved by the time `ReadJson()` is called, using it will be faster than calling `Activator.CreateInstance()`.
- Comments are not officially part of the JSON standard, but are supported by Json.NET.  If comment support is required by your application, you must skip them manually inside your `JsonConverter.Read()`.  The methods in the `JsonExtensions` class handle this automatically, and also throw exceptions when a truncated file is encountered.
- Rather than populating the list and filtering null items out afterwards, I deserialized each item individually using the non-generic [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader, Type)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize_1.htm) overload, then skipped null values before adding them to the list.
- You would need a different approach to avoid expensive reflection calls when filtering null values from generic collections such as [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) that do not implement a non-generic modifiable collection interface such as `IList`.
- If you are sensitive to performance issues, I would suggest that you avoid preloading your JSON into a temporary `JArray` inside your converter.  As noted by [11 Ways to Improve JSON Performance & Usage](https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/) by Matt Watson, loading to a `JToken` hierarchy can be up to 20% slower than deserializing directly.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e9SwlX).

Comment: Thanks for great explanations and solution. The code works perfectly fine for ([FromBody]MyModelEntity List<myModelEntity>) as per my question. However some APIs of my solutions started failing as they are not accepting List<> payloads instead they are like - public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MyModelEntity myModelEntity) 
{ ... }   OR public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(string guid)

Comment: @AnilKumar - Just to be clear, your APIs worked fine when you used your version of `NullListFilterConverter` but started to fail when you used mine?  Can you confirm?  If so I would need to see a [mcve] to help with that, for instance maybe `MyModelEntity` has a `List<T>` property that is getting nulled when it has count == 0, and the code isn't expecting that.

Comment: tnx. Your code works like charm except a case where the MyModelEntity is not of type List. I just modified your condition statement under if (!CanConvert(objectType, out var itemType)) with  return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType); and checking.

Comment: Why would `Read()` even be called in that case?  `CanConvert(Type objectType)` would have returned false so `Read()` should never have been invoked.

Comment: Yes, `CanConvert(Type objectType)` returns false and **JsonSerializationException** is thrown if the API is not accepting List of MyModelEntity. For example - 
 ` public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] MyOtherModelEntity entity)` . I need to handle this case as well. Hope I am able to explain

Comment: How are you applying the converter, such that `Read()` is called even though `CanConvert(objectType)` returns false?  You must not be adding it to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`, because if you were, `Read()` would not get called.  If you could share how you are applying the converter via a [mcve] as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75863868/3744182) to the question I could suggest workarounds.

Comment: @AnilKumar - to continue, Json.NET's architecture for converters is that `JsonConverter.Read()` is only called when `JsonConverter.CanConvert(objectType)` returns true.  If for some reason `Read()` is called even when `CanConvert(objectType)` returns false, you're fighting the architecture in a way that will cause difficulties for yourself.  So if you can share why that is happening we can suggest alternatives to avoid it.

Comment: @AnilKumar - I added a demo round-trip of a `MyModelEntity` to https://dotnetfiddle.net/e9SwlX, adding `NullListFilterConverter` to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`.

Comment: thank @dbc. I think it can perform better if we don't serialize explicitly and let the default serialize work after removing nulls from the payload.